# What is the best way to iterate over rows of a pandas dataframe whose elements are arrays of different length?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, iteration

I have a weird dataframe, where each row contains numpy arrays of different length from row to row. Below an example (actual df has more columns and waaaay more rows):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random
import string

def create_funny_string():
    adjectives = ["brilliant", "esoteric", "amazing", "curious", "enthusiastic", "lazy", "mysterious", "tricky"]
    nouns = ["hippo", "mandala", "penguin", "cat", "unicorn", "giraffe", "monkey", "spaceship"]
    return f"{random.choice(adjectives)}_{random.choice(nouns)}"

def create_random_np_array(arr_length):
    return np.random.rand(arr_length)

def create_row():
    tag = create_funny_string()
    num = random.randint(0, 10)
    array_length = random.randint(1, 10) 
    a = create_random_np_array(array_length)
    b = create_random_np_array(array_length)
    c = create_random_np_array(array_length)
    row = {"Tag": tag, "Num": num, "a": a, "b": b, "c": c}
    return row

nrows = 10
rows = [create_row() for _ in range(nrows)]
df = pd.DataFrame(rows)

print(df)
```

For each row, I want to create two plots, one of `a` vs `b` and another one of `a` vs `c`. This is clearly a "per element" iteration, meaning that it doesn't make sense to see each column as a single `np.ndarray` (also because it would be a jagged array, which isn't allowed in `numpy`). I was thinking to use `df.iterrows()`, but the Internet (and specifically this website) is full of scary stories about not using it. What should I use?

Comment: "create two plots" - what's the code where you create those plots?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest that's irrelevant to the question. You can just assume the code is created by some function which takes `df.loc[row, 'a']`, `df.loc[row, 'b']` and `df.loc[row, 'c']` as inputs.

Comment: Yes, `iterrows` is bad/slow, avoid using it. `itertuples` is faster, or just loop through the zip of columns: `for a,b,c in zip(df['a'],df['b'], df['c']): print(a,b,c)`